# How can I copy content of one file into several other files in the command line?

Tags: command-line

How can I copy the file `greetings.text` and paste its contents into `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, `4.txt` and `5.txt`?

```
$ cat greetings.text  
Hello  
Hello  
Hello  
Hello  
Hello
```

Comment: @αғsнιη That will complain about missing `{1..4}.txt` and `5.txt` not being a directory.

Comment: I don't understand all the down voting on this question, it's not a complicated question, but it's not invalid or anything. Amateurish maybe, but on it's own, that's not a bad thing.

Comment: @tommy61157 didn't downvote, but usually questions that do not express any effort to find out are not really appreciated. Don't really agree with the close votes though. We have numerous questions on text processing, always on topic.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `tee`:

```
< greetings.text tee {1..5}.txt
```

Use `tee -a` if you wish to append to the files rather than overwrite them.

Comment: i am using that but it says no such file or directory !!!

Comment: ~/shell$ cat greetings.text
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake .i was distracted.. thanks for your help

Comment: @steeldriver please note [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291065/duplicate-file-x-times-in-command-shell#comment509458_291073) that, this "_`has the defect of not preserving any file metadata`_" from **Gilles** about your answer also.

Comment: Particularly if the file is large, you might want to add `>/dev/null` afterwards to prevent unnecessary terminal output.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
cat greetings.text | tee {1..5}.txt
```

or

```
for i in {1..5} ; do cp greetings.text $i.txt ; done
```

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`.](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: Your link says that using cat followed by something is a useful use of cat. [Of course, as Heiner points out, using cat on a single file to view it from the command line is a valid use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Comment: That’s clearly not the case here though, since the output of `cat` is piped to a different command and doesn’t go to the terminal.

Comment: it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `cp` in a loop:

```sh
src=greetings.txt
for dst in {1..5}.txt; do
    cp -T -- "$src" "$dst"
done
```

If you add the `--reflink` option, `cp` will instruct the target file system to try to create a “shallow” copy of the files that only duplicates the data blocks when something modifies them. This technique is called [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#In_computer_storage).

Comment: `src=greetings.text'

Answer (score 0):

If the contents must remain the same (i.e., you don't mean to update the copied files), you can use soft or hard links:

```
for i in {00..05} ; do ln greetings.text $i.txt ; done
```

Copy is then instantaneous even with big files, and you won't use any additional disk space with the copies (I used that when I was performing tests with 200GB files). The file contents are available until the last of the copies+original is `rm`-ed.