# Create multiple files at once with the same template

Tags: command-line, 20.04, templates

I saved a template in `~/Templates` that I use very regularly. How do I create new file with same template from terminal?

Now, I'm using with `cp`

```
cp ~/Templates/cf_temp ~/Desktop/new
```

I want to create multiple files at once with template.

Is there any better way?

Comment: What is "better" in your point of view? a shorter command with less flexibility? Since "cp ~/Templates/cf_temp" will always be the same you can create a function/alias where you can replace that by a single letter `a ~/Desktop/new`  would then do the same or even `a new`  where you also include `~/Desktop/~ into the function/alias

Comment: @Rinzwind with `cp` I cannot create multiple at once, I should this to the question too.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, creating alias was the idea but I thought there some command for this or `touch` would take template as parameter when creating files.

Comment: If you want to write the same template to *multiple* files, you can either wrap `cp` in a loop, or use `tee`. See for example [How can I copy content of one file into several other files in the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082063/how-can-i-copy-content-of-one-file-into-several-other-files-in-the-command-line)

Comment: The question is about how to create a new file with that template or how to create multiple files at once with the same template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need a loop here:

```bsh
for newfile in new1 new2 new3; do 
  cp ~/Templates/cf_temp ~/Desktop/"$newfile"
done
```